# React.PropTypes.number float with min and max

Tags: javascript, reactjs, double, constraints

```
completed: React.PropTypes.number,
```

Can i specify a minimum and maximum to a number `props` in React component.

expected something like following:

```
completed: React.PropTypes.numberBetween(min, max),
```

I generate an array to specify the range

**attempt:**

```
completed: React.PropTypes.oneOf(Array.from({length: max -min+1, (v, k) => k + min})),
```

However , i want  `completed` props  to accept also float as well , whereas , it accepts only integer now .

How to make the following constraints  combined  :

- `prop` is number ( integer, float, double,...any number)
- between MIN and MAX

Comment: just wanted to tell you, `propTypes is only checked in development mode`, some how if u achieved this, then this condition will be checked in development mode only not in prod.  check this: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Custom Validation.

```
completed: function(props, propName, componentName) {
   if(props[propName] < MIN || props[propName] > MAX) {
      return new Error('Invalid');
   }
}
```

Comment: Is a `typeof props[propName] !== 'number'` check a good idea here? Or will non-numbers always fail an inequality test in JS?

Answer (score 6):

By writing a `Custom Props Validator`, u can achieve this. try this:

```
num: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if(typeof props[propName] != 'number'){
      return new Error ('Invalid type of `' + propName + '` supplied to' + ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.');
    }else if (props[propName] < MIN || props[propName] > MAX) {
      return new Error('Invalid prop `' + propName + '` supplied to' + ' `' + componentName + '`. Validation failed.');
    }
},
```

Comment: I think you want `!==` not `!=` to avoid unwanted type coercion

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I thought I would share as I ran into this issue as well.  All of the other answers address how to use this functionality for a single prop, but if you need this for multiple props, then creating a reusable PropType might be a better solution.

```js
// Allow min/max values to be passed to PropType validator
export default const numberBetween = (min, max) => {
    // Return CustomProp to be executed
    return (props, propName, componentName) => {
        const prop = props[propName];
        if(typeof prop !== 'number' || prop < min || prop > max) {
            return new Error(`Prop ${propName} must be a number between ${min} and ${max} on ${componentName}`);
        }
    }
}
```

It is then used like this:

```js
completed: numberBetween(1, 10)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Definitely should be the accepted answer here!

Answer (score 0):

The `CustomProp` just like the [`Docs`](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html) said:

```
completed: (props, propName, componentName) => 
             (props[propName] < MIN || props[propName] > MAX) && new Error('Invalid');
```