# Flow - How to check range of numbers?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I saw that Flow can [check a set of possible values](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/subtypes/) but I don't know how I can check a possible range of numbers.

When I used prop-types module, I could do a [custom validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41822323/1741027) but in Flow I don't know how I can do something like this.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: This is not possible. See my answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43394928/901387

Comment: @NatMote I read your answer. It was very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone finds this, I'm adding an answer that allows you to check for a range of numbers but requires you to create extra types to represent that information.

The upsides, is that with some upfront cost, you get both your runtime and compile time validations.

Here's the [flow.org/try link](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEGECcFMEMBdqlqeBPADk+ALBoB3JAY1gDtQBXAZyQDMB7SUAN1gBsBLAEwU4bIAodFlAB1Trk5kASuQDmSALygA3gF8A3IMEgIMBEgaVm0AB6Iy3aN1BlKAWwBG0ZiOjDMSOWUXcAco4uzCr2zq6gAGTikjjSPoraumAAahw8fAKgdJRkxPD8FLj4BEwA1tSggjl5BVkOsGXQCdDgONDETQFBrgAUZgBcdj2QAJRDAPwt3eHMqoKgoJx0oP2gAHygAAxR0WagADygAKyjaguLoHruoKTU8KgMyGRooNRPRLfkqF5f96BOWCdR6gaaBWYXRYweAmCi9fpDchocaghQ2cHBUbaRbqUDQdi0c6XUDQ2HDdjsbGgdSCGnVXL5QpvBgOVosjCUeCZMi9MJDMEjFEsBg8IlXMAAFTilVKlHYtjwLCQ71ZtwElng1AAdDraTpiAJ-g40BiIipjkk9P4GAViNg8A8pJVXJAmJUXKQaMqWWyHByuXUio1oJUUAKISrff7ub1jaaxpawABlD5IRXYD6QWAYJYPaSodqsdK8QPZBmlz4EV2IKgYQQGshG2BoFwSKSyNGgFQNJotNodLrx2MmwWJ0AAQSsBc4MuM8uyTDtVFokEqDBWkfA7M53JBeCs7CQThtOD+IcEy1WDRb0DbcQ7vmUoTl7DO80WuFdBDs0G-AFFIFdSBeixWk8QJJB32ZVktz9HdA1jZtW1ieI0VA9QgA) as a demo.

Let's say I want to make sure numbers passed in are between 0 and 5.

```
// Create a type that we can use for validation
type WithinRange = {};

// Create our extended number type
type RangedNumber = number & WithinRange;

// Validation function that works 
function makeRangeCheckedNumber(x: number): ?RangedNumber {
  if (x > 0 && x < 5) {
    // type cast to any so we can type cast back to RangedNumber
    return ((x: any): RangedNumber);
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

// function that were to take the range checked number
function someComputation(num: RangedNumber): void {
}

const myInputNumber = 5;


// So we have to wrap it in the validation function we wrote up
const maybeWithinRangeInput = makeRangeCheckedNumber(myInputNumber);

// And this would force users of someComputation to handle both cases
if (maybeWithinRangeInput == null) {
  throw new Error();
} else {
  someComputation(maybeWithinRangeInput);
}
```

Assuming you're stripping Flow types out in production builds, all the Flow types will be stripped out and you'll be left with runtime validation functions.

In your React Component, you could now use RangedNumber as well

```
type Props = {
  input: RangedNumber
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  props: Props
  ...
}
```

And anyone who wants to use your component would have to make sure to use the validation function when calling your component.

```
// Would error until they wrap this in makeRangeCheckedNumber
<MyComponent input={6} />

// This is fine
<MyComponent input={makeRangeCheckedNumber(6)} />
```

This does force consumers to call the validation function instead of having it happen automatically, but Flow will tell them to do so and you can guarantee your code to be correct.

Comment: Thank you for all this information. You put me in the right direction.